# Get Dates - Fatal Error: Maximum Execution Time Of 30 Seconds Exceeded

Tags: php

I have this code to get all the date within the range of **$from** and $to.

```
//get All days within the range.
$sStartDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($from));  
$sEndDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime($to));  
$aDays[] = $sStartDate;  
$sCurrentDate = $sStartDate;  
$allDays[] = $sStartDate;
while($sCurrentDate < $sEndDate){  
    $sCurrentDate = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($sCurrentDate)));  
    $allDays[] = $sCurrentDate;  
}
```

It's running well on my browser and computer but not on my officemate's localhost, I'm getting **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

Comment: Neither of those constants are less than 0?

Comment: Why would a positive number ever evaluate to less than zero?

Comment: hmm.. I loose my track.. Now I have this condition if($upstream > 0 && $upstream < 1 ) and it is now working

Answer (score 2):

Because both `$upstream` and `$downstream` are not less than `0`

Answer (score 1):

Both values are greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

This would cause both conditions to evaluate to true:

```
$upstream = -0.0076675415;
$downstream = -0.0067863464;
```

(As your code stands now) PHP is definitely correct in evaluating those conditions as false.

Comment: @Fred, you jumped into the OP editing grace period (5 min).

Comment: @brasofilo It happened (our edit) at the very same time. I noticed it a fraction of a second after. Not my fault.

Comment: @Fred, ok, I don't think there's a rule against it, but I wouldn't like no one editing my post while I can modify it in the first 5 minutes. I'll search in [meta.se] to see the community opinion.

Comment: @brasofilo I agree with you 100% on that. It was a pure coincidence that he and I happened to have pressed the button at the exact same time, that's all. It does happen, rarely but it does.

Answer (score 0):

They're both greater than 0.

0 = zero
0.000000001 = greater than zero